# Netlify CLI does not let me deploy my next.js application

Tags: next.js, command-line-interface, netlify

I have an ongoing issue and on another forum post I read it can be resoled by using the Netlify cli and deploying the site via the command `netlify deploy --build`. This, however, results in the following error:

```
(Netlify Build completed in 37.2s)
Deploy path: C:\Users\Me\Documents\SiteName\FolderForSite\.next
 »   TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
```

This is a next.js site.

The commands work if I run them separately (i.e. `netlify build` then `netlify deploy`), but my site ends up being a blank page.

Are there resolutions to these issues?